# Generating a random color not working

Tags: javascript, html

I was working on a simple project, to have the background of a webpage change every time you click on it. I succeeded in such, tested it a few times, save, tested again, and then left.

I go home and load it.. And it no longer works. I am using the same browser, I have no idea how anything could have changed.. I must have messed up a few ways almost impossible it feels like.. But alas, I'm sitting here dumb-founded..

Could anyone take a look at my simple program and tell me what is wrong? (Again, the program purpose is to change the webpage's background color to a random color whenever you click on the page.)

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Random Colors</title>
<script language="javascript">
    function randomColor() {
        var h0 = Math.floor(Math.random()*99);
        var h1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*99);
        var h2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*99);
        var h3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*99);
        var h4 = Math.floor(Math.random()*99);
        var h5 = Math.floor(Math.random()*99);
    return '#'.toString(16)+h0.toString(16)+h1.toString(16)+h2.toString(16);+h3.toString(16)+h4.toString(16)+h5.toString(16);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onclick="document.bgColor=randomColor();">
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Comment: please provide a fiddle.

Comment: `99`? Interesting choice of number. Anyways, a good start would be modernizing! `<!DOCTYPE html>`, `<script>`, and `document.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();`.

Comment: Just a heads up HEX values have 6 values after the "#" sign. Your function returns 5 sometimes.

Comment: Tip: `var r = function() { return Math.random() * 256 | 0; }; return "rgb(" + r() + ", " + r() + ", " + r() + ")";`

Comment: @vernak2539: `h[0..5]` is 6 (though not necessarily 6 digits, as Guffa pointed out).

Comment: It's probably this line `document.bgColor` it should be `this.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();`

Comment: Why not simply have h0 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*99)).toString(16); h1 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*99)).toString(16); ... so that in the end you have return '#' + h0 + h1 + ...

Comment: @minitech yep saw that, but when I ran it, it returned 5. Try my fiddle and sometimes it returns 5 and sometimes 6. http://jsfiddle.net/Jh5ms/

Comment: @vernak2539: That’s because there’s an extra semicolon hanging around, too. It can be as few as 3.

Comment: @minitech that's true. Put a the correct fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jh5ms/1/) and below

Comment: [Relevant code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12563/random-css-color-code)

Answer (score 3):

Having `'#'.toString(16)` makes no sense, the string `'#'` can't be converted to a string in hexadecimal form...

You have an extra semicolon after `h2.toString(16)`.

```
return '#'+h0.toString(16)+h1.toString(16)+h2.toString(16)+h3.toString(16)+h4.toString(16)+h5.toString(16);
```

I think that you want to keep each digit in the range 0-15 instead of 0-98:

```
var h0 = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
```

Comment: You're amazing, thank you so much, however it STILL doesn't seem to work. Man, this is so much worse than I thought, bahahaha.. Sorry.

Comment: Just pointing out that while `'#'.toString(16)` doesn't make sense in the context of dec->hex, the `16` will actually be ignored in this instance and you'll end up with `"#"` given back to you.

Comment: @PaulS.: Yes, it won't keep the code from working, it would just be pointless and misleading. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. Built off of what @Guffa did

```
function randomColor() {
    var h0 = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
    var h1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
    var h2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
    var h3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
    var h4 = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
    var h5 = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
    return '#' + h0.toString(16) + h1.toString(16) + h2.toString(16) + h3.toString(16) + h4.toString(16) + h5.toString(16);
}
```

Here's the fiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/Jh5ms/1/

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're using `Math.random` so many times?

```
function pad6(s) {
    s = '' + s;
    return '000000'.slice(s.length) + s;
}
function randomColor() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000);
    return '#' + pad6(rand.toString(16)).toUpperCase();
}
randomColor(); // "#7EE83D"
randomColor(); // "#19E771"
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Guffa fixing the `Math.random()*99` problem, I would put all this in a loop like this:

```
var theColor = "#";

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    theColor += Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16);
}

return theColor;
```

Here's a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89M5z/3/)**

Comment: ?? Why the downvote?? This does work no? I think it's much leaner than the other options.

Comment: Maybe because you `return`ed without a _function_? (It wasn't me that downvoted, the rest is fine)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Guffa, your first error was attempting to convert '#' to a hexadecimal representation.

This should do the trick:

```
function randomColor() {
    var ret = Math.floor(Math.random() * (0xFFFFFF + 1)).toString(16);
    return ('#' + new Array((6 - ret.length) + 1).join('0') + ret);
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
        document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
    };
};
```

[Here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/yr96jlq2) is a demonstration.

[Here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/2ybksxgn) is another demonstration showing how you could implement it into your current page. I also took the liberty of changing your event handler to be unobtrusive.

Comment: `querySelector` isn't as backwards compatible as what OP's code suggests for the intended environment, why not reference by _id_ or similar?

Comment: @PaulS. I used `querySelector` because it's only an implementation example - the main issue the OP had trouble understanding was the generation of a random colour, which I answered sufficiently.

Comment: @PaulS.: `querySelector` has IE8. OP’s code suggests Netscape. It’s pretty reasonable.

Answer (score -2):

another answer in your format - pass this to whatever you want to change backgroundcolor
http://jsfiddle.net/FpLKW/2/

```
<div onclick="test(this);">

        </div>

          function test (ele) {
                var h0 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
                var h1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
                var h2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
                var h3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
                var h4 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
                var h5 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);

            var x =  '#' + h0.toString(16) + h1.toString(16) + h2.toString(16) + h3.toString(16) + h4.toString(16) + h5.toString(16);
            ele.style.backgroundColor=x;
         }
```

Comment: I don't know how that gets down voted if it works on every click

Comment: All of the randomly generated numbers' upper bounds are one off, and you're not left-padding the resulting hexadecimal.

Comment: @Spooky: With 6 digits, no left-padding is needed. And they’re more like six off, but not *necessarily* (OP never clarified).

Comment: @minitech Reference left-padding: oh yeah, my bad. Nope, _each_ random number is one off. Wouldn't that result in the **final output** being 0x111111 off? ;)

Comment: @Spooky: Each random number is six off.

Comment: @minitech No, each random number is one off (his code is generating six random numbers).

Comment: @minitech Oops, I see it now. I was thinking in hexadecimal :/